# How to Close URL in R

Tags: r

I'm interested in using R to open and close specific URLs. I've been using the browseURL function to open a specific URL but I would then like to close that same URL from my browser after a short (manually inputted) time delay after the page has fully loaded.

Is there any function in R that will do as I described?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt so, in particular it's going to be hard to know when it has finished `fully loading`. If you don't get any other answer, I may show a `work-around` tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! I should mention that I would manually input the time delay, not automatically detect when the page is loaded. The page loads fairly quickly, so it would only be 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: ok, and what operating system / browser would you ideally like to use here?

Comment: Windows 7 using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a rather light-weight work-around for **Windows** using `SendInput`:

```
# install sendKeys library from Github
devtools::install_github("miraisolutions/winsendkeys")

# utility function that opens a URL using Chrome, 
# sleeps for a number of seconds, activates the Chrome window,
# sends CTRL+w to the active window (with a short delay to be safe).
# CTRL+w closes the current tab in Chrome. If there are no other tabs,
# Chrome will be closed. This is safer than sending ALT+F4.
myFunc <- function(URL = "https://www.stackoverflow.com", Sleep = 20) {
  # may have to adjust the path to the exe!
  browseURL(URL, browser = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")
  Sys.sleep(Sleep)
  winsendkeys::activateWindow("Chrome")
  winsendkeys::sendKeys("{DELAY=50}^w")
  NULL
}

# run example:
myFunc(Sleep = 15)
```

Note that this solution might not be super robust if you run lots of other stuff on the machine and things are lagging.
Of course it is possible to increase the DELAY from 50 to e.g. 200 if necessary.

Comment: This works great. I changed a few things in my R code to get it to run how I originally wanted it. Thanks again.